# WordPress: Why Isn't add_rewrite_rule Working?

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

## Goal

A visible URL of:

```
/products/building-automation/details/productSKU
```

Should point to the real WordPress page of:

```
/products/details/?SKU=productSKU
```

## Code

```
public function setup_frontend() {

    add_rewrite_rule(
        'products/(building-automation|lighting-controls)/details/([^/]*)',
        'products/details/?SKU=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );

    // Other code logic...

}
```

From what I can tell, the `$matches` points to the portions of the regex that are in `()`, so in the example, `$matches[1]` would be `building-automation`, and `$matches[2]` would be `productSKU`.

I have tried the flushing the rules, many times. This is being called from inside a class, but that doesn't appear to be the issue. I'm attaching the function to the `init` event.

## What is Happening

I am getting the `404` template. What am I doing wrong?

## Edit

Turns out, the second part of the parameter HAS to be `index.php`. Since I was trying to point to `products/...`, it broke. So I've updated to this:

```
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'products/(building-automation|lighting-controls)/details/([^/]*)',
        '?pagename=products/details&SKU=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
```

It's not working and point to the right page and template. However, the `$matches` part is still not coming through. In fact, `$_GET['SKU']` is coming through as `'$matches[2]'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first problem is that it's pointing to something that doesn't start with `index.php`. It has to point to `index.php?stuff`, unfortunately. But you can still use the page name, as shown below.

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'products/(building-automation|lighting-controls)/details/([^/]*)',
    'index.php?pagename=products/details&SKU=$matches[2]',
    'top'
);
```

Second, you need to register your query string, which is `SKU`. Add this:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'product_details_rewrite_filter' );

function product_details_rewrite_filter( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'SKU';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

You will still have a problem. `$_GET['SKU']` will be `$matches[2]`, not `RIBU1C`. To fix this, change `$matches[2]` to `$2`. Then it will work:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'products/(building-automation|lighting-controls)/details/([^/]*)',
    'index.php?pagename=products/details&SKU=$2',
    'top'
);
```

Comment: Yeah by trying part of your answer, it's partly working. Seems like the second param HAS to be `index.php`. However, the `term` portion of your answer isn't correct, I think. I've edited my question with the partly working new string, would you might taking a look?

Comment: Yes, sorry I replaced incorrect part of the text from the sample code.
Also, you should have this code as well so you can use $_GET['SKU'] :

`
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'product_details_rewrite_filter' );

function product_details_rewrite_filter( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'SKU';
   
    return $query_vars;
}
`

Comment: For some reason $_GET was empty for me, but get_query_var('SKU') did work.  Just in case someone in the future runs into the same issue.

Comment: "To fix this, change $matches[2] to $2" was a game changer ! 
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

1) Try to update permalinks.

Go to Dashboard->Setting->Permalinks-> button "Save changes"

2) Add action to your function

```
add_action('init', 'setup_frontend');
function setup_frontend() {

add_rewrite_rule(
    'products/(building-automation|lighting-controls)/details/([^/]*)',
    'products/details/?SKU=$matches[2]',
    'top'
);

// Other code logic...
```

}

Comment: Do you use add_action for your function?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work in this way... You trying to achive impossible with this code. Rewrites Rules in wordpress work with index.php routing, but not external pathes. So

`products/(building-automation|lighting-controls)/details/([^/]*)`

should be "translatable" to "wordpress" language (something like)

`index.php?post_type=products&category=$matches[1]&scu=$matches[1]`

notice, `scu` should also be defined as extra var.

edit 1:
Thing (I think) you trying to achive is really looks like a htaccess rule pattern, in this case you can use `mod_rewrite_rules` filter (it filter content that goes to .htaccess) to change it as you like it.

edit 2:
Advertisment - you can also use my debug bar plugin called [debug bar rewrite rules](https://github.com/butuzov/wp-debug-bar-rewrite-rules) to basically debug this data. Notice: (currently it doesn't support rules list via add_rewrite_rule, so you can only visually inspect rule, and see if it matches your expectation).

Comment: Yeah I've slowly realized that it has to point to `index.php`. It would be nice if that wasn't the case. It would actually be perfect if I could specify a URL to a page template, without needing an actual "WordPress Page" in the backend. Ah well. I'm marking Benedick's answer as the correct one because answered before you did and I said similar, but I've upvoted. Thanks, mate.